# Weird console messages when deploying app to iPad

Tags: ipad, deployment, console, debug-build

yesterday my app was deploying (debug build) to the iPad fine. but today I upgraded to iOS 4.2.1 (ie the current one),  and now it spits a lot of nonsense out on the console,  and  hangs for an indeterminate time ( sometimes a couple of minutes or more ) before finally running the app on the device.

can anyone shed some light on this Behaviour? How do I get rid of it?

PS  look at the last line:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libJapaneseConverter.dylib
```

what on earth is going on? I don't have anything to do with anything Japanese in my app,  or anywhere else in my life.   I have a couple of great Ghibli movies on my hard drive but that is it.

```
[Session started at 2011-02-14 18:30:27 +0700.]
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1510) (Fri Oct 22 04:12:10 UTC 2010)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".Loading program into debugger…
tty /dev/ttys002
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Program loaded.

unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: 

target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-918-50
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
run
Running…
[Switching to thread 11523]
[Switching to thread 11523]
continue

unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: 

warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/usr/lib/info/dns.so (file not found).
unable to load symbol file: unable to load symbol file: warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is:
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/System/Library/CoreServices/Encodings/libJapaneseConverter.dylib
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the SDK fixed it.

NB  I also set my device in to restore mode by holding down both buttons for yonks,  and letting iTunes put the latest iOS on it

EDIT:  Just talking with someone else on IRC who had the same problem --  he sorted it out by deleting his symbols folder from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/ ...  probably a bit smarter than reinstalling everything.

^^ ie exactly what Philip said above!

Answer (score 2):

You can manually delete the corresponding symbols directory. Then plug in your device, open the Organizer, and tell Xcode to load the symbols for that device.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot everything. Run Xcode then connect your device. Wait until it finishes copying symbols before doing anything. That should do it!

Comment: Is there any way to tell whether it has finished copying symbols?  ie  does it dump a log somewhere of whatever communication occurs when it is connected?

Comment: I went to Xcode -> organiser -> iPad -> device logs,  and noticed three lines http://pastebin.com/dLSKyTdW line 314.   this seems to suggest successful completion,  but deploying the project still gives the same text dump as posted in the question.